# Create a list where the even indexes have a path to a positive category and odd indexes have a path to the negative category

Tags: pytorch

I'm basically sorting my CNN images into a list with even and odd indexing. Even index will have positive images and odd index will have negative images. Here's  my code so far:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import glob
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

def show_data(data_sample, shape = (28, 28)):
    plt.imshow(data_sample[0].numpy().reshape(shape), cmap='gray')
    plt.title('y = ' + data_sample[1])

directory="/resources/data"
negative='Negative'
negative_file_path=os.path.join(directory,negative)
negative_files=[os.path.join(negative_file_path,file) for file in  os.listdir(negative_file_path) if file.endswith(".jpg")]
negative_files.sort()
negative_files[0:3]

positive="Positive"
positive_file_path=os.path.join(directory,positive)
positive_files=[os.path.join(positive_file_path,file) for file in  os.listdir(positive_file_path) if file.endswith(".jpg")]
positive_files.sort()
positive_files[0:3]

n = len(negative_files)
p = len(positive_files)
number_of_samples = n + p
print(number_of_samples)

Y=torch.zeros([number_of_samples])

Y=Y.type(torch.LongTensor)
Y.type()

Y[::2]=1
Y[1::2]=0
```

Comment: I found a method for numerical input, but not for files in a directory...

# Python code to split into even and odd lists 
# Funtion to split 
def splitevenodd(A): 
   evenlist = [] 
   oddlist = [] 
   for i in A: 
      if (i % 2 == 0): 
         evenlist.append(i) 
      else: 
         oddlist.append(i) 
   print("Even lists:", evenlist) 
   print("Odd lists:", oddlist) 
  
# Driver Code 
A=list()
n=int(input("Enter the size of the First List ::"))
print("Enter the Element of First  List ::")
for i in range(int(n)):
   k=int(input(""))
   A.append(k)
splitevenodd(A)

Comment: do you really need it like you said even:for positive and odd: for negative images? because i think may be you are looking for shuffle data [`shuffle`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.shuffle.html)

Comment: But will that place the positive and negative images in alternating order with the created 0, 1 index system = Y?

Comment: It needs to be in sequential order....not randomized.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code with:

```
directory="resources/data/"
```

Comment: Their current value is `directory="/resources/data"`. Are you saying, then, that the directory reference should not begin with a slash—but should end with one?

Comment: yes, it worked for me. Directory should either start with "." or blank.